# Como fazer para uma imagem com link aparecer um texto

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu preciso fazer um código pra que um botão (que é uma imagem) quando eu passar o mouse a imagem vai subir e um texto descer (nome do ícone da imagem), ja tentei deixar o botão com opacity(0) e um hover com opacity(1) do texto ai quando a imagem levantar o texto aparece, contudo não deu certo porque o texto fica na frente(z-index não funcionou) se alguém tiver outra ideia...

[image: Como fica] -> como fica

[image: Como deveria ficar] -> como deveria ficar (ai a imagem sobe e o titulo aparece)

[desculpa a qualidade da foto]

Comment: Você pretende usar jQuery? Tenho uma solução que esse framework para criar a animação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma simples é você usar a imagem do botão como background do link, assim você pode colocar um fundo específico para cada botão, e usar uma tag própria para o texto e fazer a transição: o botão sobe e o texto desce:

```css
body{
   background: orange;
}

.botao{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   margin: 5px;
}

.botao a{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   background-size: cover;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   transition: all .3s ease;
}

.botao a b{
   color: #fff;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: -1;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all .3s ease;
}

.botao:hover a{
   top: -15px;
}

.botao:hover a b{
   bottom: -20px;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="botao">
   <a href="#" style="background-image: url(https://static.abcteach.com/free_preview/a/astronomybnw_p.jpg);">
      <b>Astronomia</b>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="botao">
   <a href="#" style="background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfDlmiriiir4kVcIu0CDe1j0Rd2rTxD8rSPAuGBABkZZ9KpzBfFQ);">
      <b>Geografia</b>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: valeu man, consegui resolver

Answer (score 1):

Amigo se entendi bem esse é o efeito que vc precisa. Fiz do jeito mais simples para ficar mais didático.

Basicamente vc tem um *texto* com `poition:absolute` e `z-index:-1` quando vc faz o `:hover` no `.wrapper` a *img* faz um `transform:translateY(-40px)` e o *texto* aparece por traz.

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper img {
    transition: transform 500ms ease;
}
.wrapper:hover img {
    transform: translateY(-40px);
}
.wrapper .txt {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: red;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="txt">Texto</div>
    <img src="http://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando `transition` de **CSS**, é possível fazer da seguinte maneira. Você pode ver mais sobre essa propriedade na [página da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

```css
button {
  padding: 8px 14px;
  background: #0084ff;
  background-image: url("https://s19.postimg.cc/4khrr69kz/img_1.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  
  color: transparent;
  background-position: 0 0px;
  transition: .7s ease-in-out 0s;
}

button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-position: 0 -50px;
  transition: .7s ease-in-out 0s; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Uma maneira usando **jQuery** é a seguinte.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

// DOM cache
var $banner = $("#banner-message");
var $button = $("button");

// Button properties
var bColor = {
    over : $button.css("color"),
    out  : "transparent"
}

// Set color
$button.css({ "color" : bColor.out });

// Events
$button.on("mouseover", function() {
    var height = $button.css("height");
    
    $(this).animate({ 
        "background-position-y" : "-=" + height
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css("color", bColor.over);
    });
});

$button.on("mouseout", function() {
    
    $(this).css("color", bColor.out);
        $(this).animate({ 
        "background-position-y" : 0
    }, 500);
})

});
```

```css
button {
  padding: 8px 14px;
  background: #0084ff;
  background-image: url("https://s19.postimg.cc/4khrr69kz/img_1.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Mas esse script em jQuery necessitará adaptações se houver mais de um botão na página.

Comment: valeu cara, mesmo eu não tendo conseguido usar esse (muito complexo) valeu